# Add to cart glide image animation | Fly to cart image animation. PHP/jQuery/JavaScript validation on successfully adding product to cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, addtocart, validation

I am trying to make a simple glide animation when adding product to the cart to indicate and "highlight" that the product was added.

I managed to create a simple (not the best) glide animation for the time being, however, ran into a snag. I need to run the animation only when the product is actually added. Is there any way I can find that out using jQuery/JavaScript? So far, when user don't chose the "option" and adding to cart fails the validation, the animation still kicks in.

This is my code so far:

```
// Glide image to the Cart
        jQuery('#product-addtocart-button').click(function(){
            let GlideImage = jQuery('.fotorama__stage__frame > img').attr('src');
            jQuery('.product-info-main').append("<div style='position: absolute' id='glideimageclone'><img src='"+GlideImage+"' /></div>");
            jQuery(glideimageclone).animate({
                    width: "10%",
                    right: "100",
                    top: "0",
                    height: "auto",
                    opacity: "0",
            });
        });
// Glide image to the cart
```

EDIT:

I am open for PHP solutions now too.

Comment: i am not sure but if we add product in cart using ajax and when we get success in ajax response then may be we can show glide animation.

Comment: Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You have to check first that how product added to cart means ofcourse it hits some controller url so we need it hit that controller in ajax request in which we will send post data so that is how we can add product to cart once it added we need to send a response message back to ajax like success or failure  if ajax get sucess then you can show your glide animation using jquery.

Comment: @ShubhamKhandelwal I found a solution! Thanks for directing me ;)

Comment: Your welcome buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution.

I have copied the `catalog-add-to-cart.js` file from:

> vendor\Magento\Catalog\view\frontend\Web\js
>
> **to:**
>
> app\design\frontend[NameSpace][Theme]\Magento_Catalog\web\js\catalog-add-to-cart.js

And added my Glide Animation into **success: function**